# moving txt files to usb flash from Raspberry Pi device

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, usb, usb-drive, udev

For Python, When I plug my usb flash in the RaspberryPi's usb, automatically all files should move to my flash. I am not sure what should write code in script. should be Pyudev, udev or other library?
assume that flash's name is my_usb, and the files in directory of home/mydocument/projects/project3.
I need to move the files from project3 to my flash automatically (when I plug it in).

Can you write code like this? 
Thank you

Comment: Disclaimer - i DIDN'T try it myself, but the first thing that comes to mind is to monitor your mount point (probably somewhere under /media/pi) using watchdog lib (https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog).

Comment: This is not a coding service. Please try yourself first and come back when you'll encounter a specific problem. As a starting point you can learn more about `udev` rules and running scripts when a given rule is applied/triggered.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this. You need a script to copy the files to the destination directory and you need a trigger to execute this script.

Per your description the move operation can be written as a straightforward:

mv /home/mydocument/projects/project3 /my_usb

inside a shell script.

This script can then triggered automatically when the USB drive is inserted (mounted) along the lines of https://askubuntu.com/questions/25071/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-specific-flash-drive-is-mounted